# Finding derivative of $F'(-2)$

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

If $F(x)=f(g(x))$, where $f(5) = 8$, $f'(5) = 2$, $f'(−2) = 5$, $g(−2) = 5$, and 
$g'(−2) = 9$, find $F'(−2)$. I'm totally lost on this problem, I'm assuming to incorporate the Chain Rule. I get $5(5) * 9 = 225$ but I am incorrect.

Update: Thanks guys, I see where I messed up thanks!

Comment: Hint: $F'(x) = f'(g(x))g'(x)$. You will need $g(-2)$, $g'(-2)$ and $f'(5)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $$F'(x) = f'(g(x))g'(x),$$
and since we know $g(-2)$, $g'(-2)$, and $f'(5)$, we can find the final answer of
$$F'(-2) = f'(g(-2))g'(-2) = f'(5)\cdot 9 = 18.$$

Answer (score 2):

The chain rule gives $F'(x)=g'(x)f'(g(x))$. Now just substitute the values
\begin{eqnarray*}
F'(-2)=\underbrace{g'(-2)}_{9}f'(\underbrace{g(-2)}_{5})=9\underbrace{f'(5)}_{2}=9 \times 2 =\color{red}{18}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

$F'(x)=f'(g (x))\cdot g'(x) $, by the chain rule. ..  I'm getting 18...